# How to write large amount of data into file using php functions

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, file

I am developing CMS kind of website where I am using rich text editor to edit text of templates and I am try to save edited content on text files. Its working fine but when large amount of data send for save then some paragraph contents are truncated. I am using ajax to send data into back-end.

This is my php code for writing into the file

```
<?php
$file = fopen("../include/banner.html","w+");

     fwrite($file,$_POST['param']);

fclose($file);
?>
```

my ajax code

```
var editor_data = CKEDITOR.instances.banner.getData(); 
   alert(editor_data); 

var param = 'param=' + editor_data; 

  $.ajax( { 
    type: "POST", 
    url:'./php/banner.php', 
    dataType:'html', 
    data: param, });
```

---

Can anyone help me to provide solution for writing large amount of data into text files using php. If am enter jast 2-3 lines its working fine but when more than 20 lines its not working properly some contents are truncated.

Comment: how I can configure code to use more memory ram

Comment: You need more memory (RAM) i would say. How much is large in your case?

Comment: can you also put up your code used to send the AJAX POST request with the data?

Comment: Please provide some idea or code which I can use in my code

Comment: how about slicing files into pieces and read each of it ?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039824/php-script-to-split-large-text-file-into-multiple-files

Comment: its possible I can use while loop with $_POST['data'] like for checking codition.

Comment: while($_POST['data']!=null){$buffer= fgets($handle, 4096); fwrite($file,$buffer);}

Comment: Check your PHP server configuration, i.e. config item named `max_post_size` and compare the value with the size of your post request. If the latter is larger that the first, you sould consider updating your config to allow larger post requests, to reach the server.

Answer (score 0):

I would serialize your data when you write it to the file.

```
file_put_contents( "../include/banner.html", json_encode($_POST) );
```

So that way your data is still in JSON format when your ajax call parses it.

Comment: I have to send data in json formate as well while sending ajax request to php backend